# How can I catch uri where a request arrive?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

How can I catch uri where a request arrive? I have a jsp file that it has a form which submit action to myServlet. Also, I have a filter between them. That is: 
index.jsp --> myfilter --> myServlet.
Is there any way to know uri or url "index.jsp" into the myfilter?.
I've tried a lot of ways with nothing results: getRequestURI, getRequestURL show "myServlet" as a uri/url...

Edit:
Thanks but it doesn't work for me.
In the filter I have made:

```
String url = (String)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");<br>
System.out.println("URL source: "+url);<br>
--> and the output is --> URL source: null<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write below lines to get original URI in your filter.

```
String url = (String)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
```